# OCL constraint UML Profile Rational Software Architect

Tags: profile, ocl, stereotype

I have a UML Profile that I need to add a constraint to my stereotype of ModeBehaviour which is an extension of StateMachine.

Constraint: Owned States must be stereotyped as Mode, and Owned Transitions must be stereotyped as ModeTransition

For the first part of the constraint I am thinking it may begin with: self.submachine as this will refer to the owned states of ModeBehaviour?  From there I don't know how to see if these states are stereotypes as Mode.

Any direction would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether an Element has a particular stereotype attached, just use the `getAppliedStereotype` function. For example, if you want to find out whether the **self** element has the *MyStereotype* stereotype from the *MyProfile* profile, use

`self.getAppliedStereotype("MyProfile::MyStereotype") <> null`

Adapting it to your particular use is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  How would you refer to owned states or owned transitions.  For owned states I have self.submachineState and I am unsure for owned transitions.  Do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one, but if it is anything like associations in class diagrams, you can treat the other end of the transition as an attribute.